# How can i goto appdelegate class

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application. In that I set the notification in viewcontroller1. And close the application.

After getting the notification I am directly going to viewcontroller1 xib not main xib. I written code like that. But my problem is after coming to viewcontroller1 xib,that contain the cancel button. When I click on cancel button I need to go to appdelegate class. But its not going. That cancel button is working when I come from appdelegate class. But its not working when I come directly to this class.

That cancel method contain `[self.view dismissviewcontroller];`, so please tell me how can I go to appdelegate class when I click on cancel button.

Comment: appdelegate class? do you manin the mainview controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Get appdelegate object

Comment: After getting that object what i cando?

Comment: u have to make a UIView object in appdelegate and presentmodel on it. after cancel that u have to go where ur normal flow going right then need to manage of controller, what controller ur using nav or tab based. then manage view controller. It is normal way to manage push on appdelegate view model and handler. 
what exactly u want explain more. I didnt get u exactly.